# C++ pointers char

Tags: c++

What happens after running this code?

```
  char* c= "abc";
  void* p= &c;
  printf("%s %s", *(char**) p, *(char*) p);
```

So c points to string and p too. But I don't get what all the * truly do.
Someone can explain me?

Comment: A compiler error, that's what happens.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar [Not really](http://ideone.com/Hmt3Ev)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - okay, a warning, then. :)

Comment: You should obey every waning your [compiler tells](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e32eb641dc77704) you. You're invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in the printf line causes the problem, because it will interpret the content of p as a string, rather than a pointer to a string. The printf line could be:

```
printf("%s %c", *(char**)p, *c);
```